# mysqli_rollback($conn) Not Woking

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, innodb, rollback

I am trying to test transaction in php with mysql database(InnoDB) but the rollback is not working...

This is my code

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "test";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE);    

    mysqli_query($conn,"update person set Balance = 300 where Name = 'Jay'");
    if ($conn->affected_rows > 0) {
        mysqli_commit($conn);
        echo "First Commited <br>";
        mysqli_query($conn,"update person set Balance = 3000 where Name = 'Rv'");       
        if($conn->affected_rows > 0) {
            mysqli_commit($conn);
            echo "Second Commited <br>";
        }else {
            mysqli_rollback($conn);
            echo "First rollback <br>";
        }       
    }   
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Is there anything wrong? (I have also try object oriented style in php, Refer from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php))

[SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kxJX.png) person query result

Comment: I think it has to do with the commit after `if($conn->affected_rows`. As seen in an example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php#refsect1-mysqli.commit-examples) there are multiple queries executed before calling commit, and autocommit never got reset to true

Comment: Can you confirm exactly what IS happening?  Are you getting both updates? or just one?  You should not mix procedural with object-oriented styles, just pick one.

Comment: If the execution of second query failed then the first commit should be rollback according to else block but it doesn't work, commit doesn't rollback

Comment: The autocommit not being reset doesn't matter in this case purely as the connection is closed at the end of the script.

Comment: Answer is given in this post. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44681056/4646166)